# Fix UIPageControl (not slide)

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I have implemented UIPageControl for my PageViewController in the Storyboard, configured there the number of pages needed, and then added `self.pageControl setCurrentPage:self.pageIndex];` in viewDidLoad of my content view controller. However, whenever I slide the pages the page indicator (grey dots) move with the views. How can you fix the page indicator so it's only the views that slide?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've added your `pageControl` to a child controller in your `PageViewController`. Try to add it to parent (container) controller.